# App Store: can't add a new credit card (too many are already associated)

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, itunes-store

I use virtual credit cards to perform online purchases with my debit card, and I usually create a new one for every purchase (with a charge limit equal to the purchase's value).

I was trying to add a new one today to buy an app on the Mac App Store, and I got a message saying that it couldn't be added, as there were already too many credit cards associated with my account.

I did a live-chat with support, and they told me that there is a 5-card limit every 30 days, so apparently I can't perform any purchases for 30 days.

Is there any way around this? I don't have iTunes Gift Cards readily available in my country.

Comment: That is odd for even Apple to turn down money...

Comment: It seems to be some anti-fraud or anti-theft mechanism, as I agree, having multiple cards may seem suspicious. However, other companies like Amazon allow me to delete previous cards. And Steam did block my purchases once, but all it took was a support e-mail explaining the situation for them to lift the limits on my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for documenting the current state of play. Although most can buy gift cards from the store of your choice and load them into the App Store, if they truly are not easily available in your country just slowing down the cycling of cards you use for payment is the obvious choice out of this dilemma.

Comment: That's what I intend on eventually doing (after the 30 days), but I did want to buy an app now (it's on sale). Being locked out of the stores (both iTunes and App stores) for 30 days is something that I would've liked to avoid.

Comment: Can't you add funds to one of the prior cards or ask them in support to add one more manually now that you understand that what you were doing would end up with your account locked out? Also - you can have a friend gift you the app or sign up for a new one time account if no friends are willing to help you out.

Comment: Prior cards are deleted by my bank's system once the charge limit is passed (and that limit is fixed), and also I only have access to their details immediately after their creation. Afterwards I can check which purchases were made on each card but I can't for instance check their CVV. I'll try asking support, but having a friend gift me the app is a good idea, I hadn't thought of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get that one app, perhaps you could ask somebody to gift it to you.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201783